# R convert data.frame to list by column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to convert a data.frame into a list of data.frames by column using base R functions and holding the first column constant.  For example, I would like to split DF into a list of three data.frames, each of which includes the first column.  That is, I would like to end up with the list named LONG without having to type out each list element out separately.  Thank you.

```
DF <- data.frame(OBS=1:10,HEIGHT=rnorm(10),WEIGHT=rnorm(10),TEMP=rnorm(10))
DF

LONG <- list(HEIGHT = DF[c("OBS", "HEIGHT")],
             WEIGHT = DF[c("OBS", "WEIGHT")],
             TEMP   = DF[c("OBS", "TEMP"  )])

LONG

SHORT <- as.list(DF)
SHORT

SPLIT <- split(DF, col(DF))
```

Comment: On using `split.default` to split data frame by column: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can loop through the `names` of 'DF' except the first one, `cbind` the first column with the subset of 'DF' from the `names`.

```
setNames(lapply(names(DF)[-1], function(x) cbind(DF[1], DF[x])), names(DF)[-1])
```

Or another option would be

```
Map(cbind, split.default(DF[-1], names(DF)[-1]), OBS=DF[1])
```

Comment: Why split.default and not just split?

Comment: @user1491868  It is to `split` the dataset into list of dataframes based on the patterns of names.  In this case, even `Map(cbind, DF[-1], OBS = DF[1])` should work